# Color change event handling in jpicker

Tags: jquery, html, jpicker

I have several jpickers. For ex: I want to change body background color meanwhile changing color in jpicker. How to handle color change event in jpicker?

**js:**

```
$('#colorSelector').jPicker(
                {
                    window:{expandable:true}
                });
```

**html**

```
<span id="colorSelector"></span>
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'I want to change body background color meanwhile changing color in jpicker' did you mean that when you change color in jpicker the body background should change to that color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$('#Callbacks').jPicker(
        {},
        function(color, context)
        {
          var all = color.val('all');
          alert('Color chosen - hex: ' + (all && '#' + all.hex || 'none') + ' - alpha: ' + (all && all.a + '%' || 'none'));
          $('#Commit').css(
            {
              backgroundColor: all && '#' + all.hex || 'transparent'
            }); // prevent IE from throwing exception if hex is empty
        }
);
```

Look there: http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/